# passing variables from bash to executable (which reads argument with stdin)

Tags: bash, variables, executable, stdin

I have the following **test.cpp** c++ program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float a,b,c;
    cout<<"Give 1st number";
    cin>>a;
    cout<<"Give 2nd number:";
    cin>>b;

    c=a+b;
    cout<<"\n"<<a<<"+"<<b<<"="<<c<<endl;

return 0;
}
```

and I want to create a **shell script** which gives the input variables.
I know how to pass one variable, and I would like to know if there is a way to **pass 2 variables**...
like the following **test.sh** file which is not working

```
#!/bin/bash

g++ test.cpp -o testexe
chmod +x testexe

a=1
b=2

./testexe <<< $a $b
```

Comment: You mean like `echo $a $b | ./testexe`?

Comment: `./testexe <<<$'$a\n$b\n'` or similar should work too `$''` needed to get a literal newline in there (for single line demonstration) but could be done over multiple lines otherwise.

Comment: Since this is about the shell part and not the C++ part you might want to loose the c++ tag. Or else some C++ guy might read the question and give a lengthy wail about that code (repeated includes, unnecessary includes, C-header includes, questionable using directive, weird indentation, Missingwhitespacetomakeyourcodeunreadable,...)

Comment: I want variables to be passed to testexe file, just by running test.sh file...
_./testexe <<<$'$a\n$b\n'_ isn't working 
I want to to do something like `./testexe <<< $a` 
which passes one variable, but now with two variables

Comment: @EtanReisner, `$'$a\n$b\n'` won't expand the variables.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Good point. I'd assumed it would (I basically never use it) since it expands the escapes. So `<<"$a"$'\n'"$b"` would be necessary for single-line usage (assuming the input needs to be newline split).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be compatible with not just bash, but also `/bin/sh` -- while avoiding pipeline overhead -- use a heredoc:

```
./testexe <<EOF
$a
$b
EOF
```

If you don't care about pipeline overhead (and still maintaining `/bin/sh` compatibility, which any answer using `<<<` lacks):

```
printf '%s\n' "$a" "$b" |  ./testexe
```

If you don't care about `/bin/sh` compatibility:

```
./testexe <<<"$a"$'\n'"$b"
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change your C++ program and script as follows :

```
int main(int argc, const char*argv[])
{
    float a,b,c;
    a=std::stof(argv[1]);
    b=std::stof(argv[2]);
    c=a+b;
    cout<<"\n"<<a<<"+"<<b<<"="<<c<<endl;
    return 0;
}


#!/bin/bash

g++ test.cpp -o testexe
chmod +x testexe

a=1
b=2

./testexe  $a $b
```

Comment: Sidesteps the question rather than answering it, no?

Comment: `
test.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
test.cpp:12:6: error: cannot convert ‘char*’ to ‘float’ in assignment
     a=argv[1];
      ^
test.cpp:13:6: error: cannot convert ‘char*’ to ‘float’ in assignment
     b=argv[2];
      ^
Give 1st number:^C
`

Comment: @OrestisKotsas, ...to be clear, by the way -- sidestepping the question *is* the right thing to do. You should take arguments off of the command line, not stdin, when you can.

Comment: @ Charles Duffy
_sidestepping the question_ ? What you mean? Forgive me, but my english is not in a very good level...
This is an example of the code that I am dealing with, and it is not easy to change the structure of the code. I just wanted the basic idea...

Comment: @OrestisKotsas, "sidestepping the question", meaning doing something that avoids the problem you asked about, rather than actually solving the literal problem as asked. In this case, reading arguments off the command line (from the argv array) is better practice than reading them from stdin, but you asked specifically about stdin -- so a direct answer would involve stdin; this one tries to show you a better practice instead (though it's buggy).

Comment: @Steephen, I'm having trouble compiling this as updated (`error: ‘stof’ is not a member of ‘std’`). That said, I'm a C developer from way back who's always had a passionate hatred of C++, so this could be a trivial fix I'm unaware of.

Comment: @OrestisKotsas const char* to float conversion is taken care, Thanks to point it out.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
echo "$a $b" | ./testexe
```

Or:

```
arr=("$a" "$b")
./testexe <<< "${arr[*]}"
```

Or:

```
./testexe <<< "$a $b"
```

Or:

```
./testexe <<< "$a"$' '"$b"
```

If you want it to work for string variables too (with white spaces), then use **new line** as separator between two variables instead of a single space.

Ex:

```
echo "$a"$'\n'"$b" | ./testexe
```

Comment: `echo $a $b` works here, where values are guaranteed to be numbers (unless `IFS` is set to a value containing digits in those numbers, in which case this would break without quotes), but it's an iffy practice in general -- arguments get string-split and glob-expanded. Let's say you were passing in a filename rather than a number; if that name were something like `*** HELLO WORLD ***.txt`, then the first set of `*`s would be glob-expanded, and replaced with filenames from the current directory, while the second set would be replaced with a list of text file names.

Comment: Thus, `echo "$a $b"` is a safer replacement; likewise, `printf '%s %s\n' "$a" "$b"`.

Comment: Thanks, @CharlesDuffy, I added your suggestion.

Comment: The array suggestion currently given doesn't fix the globbing problems, since you're still doing unquoted assignments when putting values into the array, and has potential forward-compatibility issues since the semantics of `${foo[@]}` are undefined (and thus, open to change) when treated as a scalar value (you should use `"${foo[*]}"` in that case).

Comment: So: `arr=( "$a" "$b" ); ./testexe <<<"${arr[*]}"` would be more correct.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, yap, fixed that.

Comment: Still should be `[*]` rather than `[@]` since the value is intended to be a scalar. That said, this is now very close to having my upvote. :)

Comment: @Jahid
`arr=("$a" "$b")

./testexe <<< "${arr[@]}"`
works only if you use **char** variables..
in my case (float variables) it would be
`arr=($a $b)`
which is working..
The other methods are working fine! Thank you!

Comment: @OrestisKotsas, pardon? `arr=("$a" "$b"); ./testexe <<<"${arr[*]}"` still works perfectly fine with numbers -- things are *all* in string form by the time they're passed to stdin, which is, after all, nothing but a stream of bytes.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance @CharlesDuffy, If you could give me some reference about this [*] scenerio, that would be good, I am not still quite clear about that.

Comment: @Jahid, `${foo[*]}` combines an array into a string by separating each element by the first character of `IFS`, or a space by default. By contrast, `"${foo[@]}"` emits the array as separate elements when quoted. When it's not quoted, or in a scenario where only a single string is usable, its behavior is more ambiguous, which is why `"${foo[*]}"` is preferable in those cases (but only those cases).

Comment: ...to restate: if you want to start another program with exact arguments from an array, `"${arr[@]}"` is correct; when you want to combine an array into a string (and `<<<` takes a string), `"${arr[*]}"` is correct.

Comment: @Charles Duffy I apologise..! my mistake.. It is working fine!
Thank you for your help!

Comment: @CharlesDuffy So if I qoute `"${arr[@]}"` then it won't produce any unexpected result in the current situation, right?

Comment: @Jahid, in the context of `<<<`, only a single value is expected, but `"${arr[@]}"` expands to multiple values. Thus, by a strict reading of the language specification, this would not work. The fact that it *does* work is thus taking advantage of an undocumented feature, and undocumented features (as opposed to explicit ones) can be removed from future versions of the language without notice. Thus, it's a forward-compatibility issue.

Comment: I get it now, thnks @CharlesDuffy, `<<<` expects single value. So [*] is the right choice here, because it produces a single string with space separated (by default) values.